# Django 1.8 change navbar-static-top.css colour, collectstatic, but doesn't work

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I've been doing a web tutorial to learn Django, and I got stuck on video 31 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8Pt8n0IAQ0). I've checked some other posts here but haven't found a solution.

It all worked fine till here. I want to change the colour of the top navbar, which is a CSS file called navbar-static-top.css, which I have stored in two routes in my project. 
/static_in_env/static_root/css        and      /static_in_pro/our_static/css

I've got the settings file configured properly I think. 
I wrote this code in the navbar-static-top.css file to change the colour,

```
.navbar-static-top {
  margin-bottom: 19px;
  background-color: #137937;
}
```

Then I used the header {% load staticfiles %} in my base.html template. Everything seems to be good.

I also did python manage.py collectstatic, and the message I receive is that everything was compiled properly, I get the same message as the video tutorial.

But then it doesn't work. The navbar colour doesn't change.

I also tried the same for an image (video 32 of the tutorial), stored it in the our_static/img and static_root/img folders, did manage.py collectstatic, and then wrote the following code in the navbar.html template to insert the image.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}"><img src="{% static 'img/mvp_landing_logo.png' %}"></a>
```

And then I can't see the picture.

Something is wrong with my static files and I'm pretty frustrated and stuck, can't find what's going on.

Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: I think you misspelled your class `navbar-static-top` in the `<a ...` tag

Comment: Checked it out and it wasn't that, the guy in the tutorial has the same code I have.

Don't know it's weird that it doesn't work both for changing the navbar color using a static CSS file, and for displaying a static image. Seems like something with the static integration is wrong.

Comment: I think you should use your browser console to determine if the style is loading properly and go from there.

Comment: You can also check in your browser what URL was generated for the image. It's probably not what you expected, or collectstatic did not store the files at this location.

Comment: To partially solve it I just copied the source code of the tutorial I'm doing and that worked. But I'm still having trouble with the image. When I inspect the element, it says it is in

/static/img/mvp_landing_logo.png


I don't have  a folder called "static" anywhere in my project, that would make sense why the file is not found. But the guy from the tutorial neither has one.

Comment: I have src/static_in_pro/our_static, and also at the same level of src is a folder called static_in_env/static_root. In both of those are the css, img, js and psd folders.

My settings file has the following:

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_in_env", "static_root")
    
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_pro", "our_static"),
    #os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_env"),
    #'/var/www/static/',
)

please help, im not understanding the static files concept or how to fix this, to find the image and display it